# Что лучше, два метода или один с параметром по умолчанию?

Tags: c#, ооп, архитектура, solid

В самописной библиотеке есть метод который может принимать как один параметр так и два, если один, то для второго у нас есть дефолт.
Вопрос в том как лучше сделать, создать два перегруженных метода в интерфейсе или создать один но с вторым параметром по умолчанию?

```cs
// 1.

interface IExample {
    void Method(int a);
    void Method(int a, int b);
}

// 2.

interface IExample {
    void Method(int a, int b = DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: в системной библиотеке `Console.ReadKey` по второму способу сделали

Comment: Если значение параметра по умолчанию вычисляемое, то второй вариант в принципе невозможен, ибо ограничение языка

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если Вы сами говорите, что для второго параметра в случае его неуказания будет назначено значение по умолчанию, то написание двух методов просто бессмысленно. Это тратит память на сохранение двух разных методов с, по сути, идентичным функционалом.

Второй вариант однозначно лучше. Перегруженные методы создаются в тех случаях, когда во втором (n-ом в общем случае) параметре нет необходимости и он никак не участвует в вычислениях, производимых методом.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ. Возникает еще вопрос, где хранить дефолтное значение? В первом случае когда у меня два полиморфных метода я могу хранить в классе имплементации константу или что там у меня дефолтное а в случае когда мне надо задефолтить параметр в интерфейсе мне прям в параметре хардкодить или можно кудато по красивее вынести?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov я чаще всего явно указываю, чему будет равно значение. Это даже хардкодом и не назовешь. Значение под рукой и больше оно нигде не встречается, так зачем тогда его где-то отдельно выносить? Его следует вынести только в случае, если оно еще где-то в коде используется повторно.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov В этом вопросе я уже менее компетентен, но точно могу сказать, что даже в стандартных библиотеках значения параметров по умолчанию прописываются сразу в интерфейсе, чтобы пользователь, который будет вызывать этот метод, мог сразу видеть, что будет присвоено этому параметру в случае, если он его не укажет.

Comment: @V-Mor если через объявленную константу указывать значение по умолчанию для метода, то IntelliSence будет подставлять это значение в подсказку, поэтому в любом случае пользователь функции будет видеть, какое именно значение будет передаваться в случае, если его не указывать

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ, как решение, если он был полезен.